# Web API Redirect on Azure saying that resource is unavailable

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have a web api where a user sends a token containing his/her e-mail and the url where the user needs to be redirected to. This works fine when I test it on localhost, but whenever I host it in Azure it gives me the following message:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I'm quite new to Azure and the way .NET API's handle the Redirect method.

The following link

> myapi.azurewebsites.net/api/mail/track/click/verylongtoken

has the following code

```
    [HttpGet("track/click/{token}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> TrackClick(string token)
    {
        var stat = await _context.Stats.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Datum == DateTime.Today);
        var _token = await _context.TrackingToken.SingleOrDefaultAsync(tt => tt.Token == token);

        GeneratedToken decoded = new GeneratedToken();
        decoded = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeneratedToken>(hasher.DecodeHash(token));

        if (_token != null)
        {
            if (stat == null)
            {
                Stats _stat = new Stats();
                _stat.Datum = DateTime.Today;
                _stat.Geopend = 0;
                _stat.Geklikt = 0;
                _stat.Verstuurd = 0;

                _context.Stats.Add(_stat);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                stat = await _context.Stats.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Datum == DateTime.Today);
            }

            stat.Geklikt++;

            _context.TrackingToken.Remove(_token);
            _context.Entry(stat).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        return Redirect("http://"+decoded.link);
    }
```

As you can see I'm also deleting the token after the first request. I know this could cause the problem but the problem also occurs when I use a fresh unused token. The code works perfectly on localhost but I'm suspecting that Azure is preventing this request.

Postman also doesn't give me some more detailed information.

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Could you provide a sample url link? If the link is a third party website, it will always work on azure.

Comment: already posted a sample url, don't feel safe to just hand you an active testing URL.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but I resolved it :

- I use CORS to prevent cross domain error (see with F12 on chrome) and
  add the allowed adress in CORS section on Azure App service (add "*"
  if you using security token in your app)
- I have the same issue when I
  deployed using "Continuous delivery" section on VS2017. To deploy on
  Azure, I create fist my Appservice on Azure, I export the appService
  profile and import it on VS2017 when I publish.

And with that, its work fine.